# Computing elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})$ with good ordinary reduction at $\mathfrak{p}\mid 3$ in Sage

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, computational-mathematics, sagemath

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for $\alpha=\sqrt{-11}$. Since $-11 \equiv 1\pmod 3$ is a square, there is a factorization:
$$ 3\mathcal{O}_K=((1/2)\alpha-(1/2))((1/2)\alpha+(1/2)) = \mathfrak{p}_1\mathfrak{p}_2 $$

By Theorem 4.1 of Silverman's AEC:

> Theorem 4.1: Let $E/\mathbb{F}_3$ be an elliptic curve given by a Weierstrass equation $$ E:y^2 = f(x) $$ where $f(x)\in \mathbb{F}_3[x]$ is a cubic polynomial with distinct roots in an algebraic closure. Then $E$ is supersingular if and only if the coefficient of $x^2$ is zero in $\mathbb{F}_3$.

Thus, I expect most elliptic curves $E/K$ with good reduction to be ordinary when reduced at either $\mathfrak{p}_1$ or $\mathfrak{p}_2$. Therefore, to verify this, I ran the following snippet over a large set of elliptic curves $E/K$ defined by $y^2 = x^3 + Ax+B$ with bounded coefficients $A,B\in\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $\text{max}(|A|^4,|B|^6)\leq N$ for some fixed $N$.

```
K.<a> = NumberField(x^2+11)
v1 = K.ideal(3).factor()[0][0]
v2 = K.ideal(3).factor()[1][0]

...

total_count = 0

good_at_v1 = 0
good_at_v2 = 0
good_at_v1_and_v2 = 0

good_ordinary_at_v1 = 0
good_ordinary_at_v2 = 0
good_ordinary_at_v1_and_v2 = 0

for (A,B) in some list:

    ...

    E = EllipticCurve([A,B])
    da1 = E.local_data(v1)
    da2 = E.local_data(v2)

    gv1 = da1.has_good_reduction()
    gv2 = da2.has_good_reduction()
        
    ov1 = False
    ov2 = False
        
    if gv1:
        good_at_v1 = good_at_v1 + 1
        ov1 = True if da1.minimal_model().reduction(v1).is_ordinary() else False
    if gv2:
        good_at_v2 = good_at_v2 + 1
        ov2 = True if da2.minimal_model().reduction(v2).is_ordinary() else False
    if gv1 and gv2:
        good_at_v1_and_v2 = good_at_v1_and_v2 + 1

    if ov1 and ov2:
        good_ordinary_at_v1_and_v2 = good_ordinary_at_v1_and_v2 + 1
        
    total_count = total_count + 1
```

At the end of this code sequence, I get the following statistic:

- $~65.8\%$ curves have good reduction at `v1`
- $~65.8\%$ curves have good reduction at `v2`
- $~44.7\%$ curves have good reduction at both `v1` and `v2`
- $0$ curves have good and ordinary reduction at `v1`
- $0$ curves have good and ordinary reduction at `v2`

There are at least $50,000$ curves in my list, everything up to $N=200$. I'm baffled because it does not seem possible to get literally zero curves with good and ordinary reduction at either prime dividing $3$. Does anyone spot any obvious mistakes in my understanding, or my code? Something that I noticed is that for all of the Weierstrass equations in my list, `.minimal_model()` returns the exact same equation, and hence (by Theorem 4.1) every equation of the form $y^2 = x^3 + Ax+ B$ reduces to a supersingular curve (if it has good reduction). I have tried to use `.minimal_model(reduce=False)` but it returns the same results.

I hope this question is sufficiently mathematical to belong on math.SE. If not, please direct me to another active community where I should post this question instead. Thanks!

**Edit 1.** As @Mindlack points out in the comments, $E = X_0(11)$ has good ordinary reduction at $3$.
$$ E: y^2 + y = x^3 - x^2 - 10x - 20 $$
It has short Weierstrass form $E': y^2 = x^3 -13392x-1080432$. Using Sage, I found the minimal models at `v1` of both equations.
$$ \begin{align*}
E &: y^2 + y = x^3 - x^2 - 10x - 20 \tag{did not change} \\
E' &: y^2 = x^3 + (-\tfrac{1}{2}\alpha-\tfrac{1}{2})x^2 + (\tfrac{827}{2}\alpha-\tfrac{1159}{2})x + (-11829\alpha-6556)
\end{align*}
$$
Reducing the coefficients modulo `v1` gets tells us that $\overline{E}$ and $\overline{E'}$ are both ordinary. So it doesn't seem like `.minimal_model()` is at fault here.

Comment: Why isn’t the third point in the results contradicting the two previous ones? You seem to have more curves with good reduction at both places than curves with good reduction at, say, $v_1$…

Comment: Sorry, I got the statistic backwards. I have updated the post.

Comment: Second: if I’m not mistaken (my theory of elliptic curves is a little bit rusty), $X_0(11)$ has good ordinary reduction at $3$. So this should still hold when we consider the base change of the curve to $K$, right?

Comment: Good point. I made an edit to the post to show my calculations for $X_0(11)$. It doesn't seem like Sage is at fault here.

Comment: If you continue to compute this sort of data and want to compare it against other data, see the LMFDB. (For example, [this search](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/2.0.11.1/?hst=List&field=2.0.11.1&bad_quantifier=exclude&conductor_norm_factors=3&search_type=List) is relevant). Note also that the LMFDB is very happy to talk to others about including more data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a curve $y^2 = x^3 + a x + b$ with relatively small $a$ and $b$, you are preselecting for curves which are already in minimal Weierstrass form at (a prime above) $3$, and thus which will either have bad reduction or supersingular reduction at $3$. So your sample space is biasing the results. In particular, I think that the only way your curve could have good reduction at (all primes above) $3$ is if $27|a$ and $27|b$. This is already outside your range if I understand it.

As a comparison, if you look at $y^2 = x^3 + a x + b$ but now with $a,b \in \mathbf{Z}$ in a small box you won't find any curves with good ordinary reduction at the prime $3$ either.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct in that $27\mid a,b$ is necessary for a curve to have good ordinary reduction at all primes above $3$. Thanks for your comment. Most of the curves with $27\mid a,b$ actually do not have good reduction, so it seems like good ordinary reduction is actually far and few in between for primes over $3$...

Comment: @klein4 but to repeat my point, if you count elliptic curves in a way that makes good ordinary primes less likely then they will be...less likely. For an analogy in one dimension lower, if you take a random quadratic $x^2 + c$ for integers $c$, the chance the splitting field has good reduction at $2$ will only be $1/3$, but that's because $x^2 + c \bmod 2$ is never separable. If you take $x^2 + b x + c$ for random $b$ and $c$  then the chance it is unramified at $2$ increases to $2/3$. Similarly if you take $y^2 = x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c$ then there will be many more good ordinary curves.